# Rendering more than one object at a time

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am trying to render multiple objects as JSON. My controller code looks like:

```
 def showClient = {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        def q_param = params.name_startsWith;
        def listOfClients =ClientRole.findAll("FROM ClientRole WHERE  party.name LIKE ? AND is_active =true",["%"+q_param+"%"])
        def point= Point.get(1)

        ArrayList<DisplayableName> clientList = ParameterFormatter.getFormattedDisplayNameList(listOfClients)
        def json = clientList as JSON
        log.debug("showClients :: jsondata = "+json)
        render json
    }else{
        redirect(controller:'login',action: "auth")
    }
}
```

Here I am rendering only `clientList` as json, but I also want to render the `point` object. How can I render both `clientList` and `point` object at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
render(contentType: 'text/json') {
    delegate.clientList = clientList
    delegate.point = point
}
```

This will result in a JSON object like:

```
{
    "clientList": [ /* client list */ ],
    "point": { /* point object */ }
}
```

Comment: Can you pls explain me what really happens there... and how to get the values an View

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what else to explain, and I don't follow the second part of your comment. Maybe have a read through the [documentation for rendering JSON](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7 XML and JSON Responses)? Perhaps that'll clear a few things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

I always put everything in a map before rendering as JSON! so try this:

```
def showClient = {
    if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
        def q_param = params.name_startsWith;
        def listOfClients =ClientRole.findAll("FROM ClientRole WHERE  party.name LIKE ? AND is_active =true",["%"+q_param+"%"])
        def point= Point.get(1)

        ArrayList<DisplayableName> clientList = ParameterFormatter.getFormattedDisplayNameList(listOfClients)
        def map = [clients:clientList]
        map << [point:point]
        def json = map as JSON
        render json


    }else{
        redirect(controller:'login',action: "auth")
    }
}
```